# Change ssh tunnel after connecting

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

Is it possible to change/add an ssh tunnel after connecting to the ssh server via command line? I know you can do it with putty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your using OpenSSH, you can use the escape characters to add/remove tunnels.

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1#ESCAPE+CHARACTERS

Note:

- While typing the escape character, it won't actually appear in the terminal.
- An escape character should follow a newline.

Example: Adding a local port forwarding of 1234 to 1234

```
~C
L1234:127.0.0.1:1234
```